# SSIS deployed package cannot convert DTWSTR to NUMERIC

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Package, which has a Data Conversion Task. In this task I would like to convert `DTWSTR 2000` to `NUMERIC(36,10)`

[image]

The data in organic column is something like this:

[image]

I can run my package successfully in Visual Studio, but after I deploy the package to SQL Server and run it with the same input parameters, I get this error:

> The conversion returned status value 2 and status text. The value could not be converted because of potential loss of data

Why I can run the package in Visual Studio but not on SQL Server?

Comment: Looks like the conversion is set to fail on a truncation error. What number is `175,06845...`  meant to represent? If `,` is a decimal point, then you need a much bigger scale, however, if it's not, why is there only 1 comma? I would expect something more like `175,068,4...`.

Comment: It is a decimal point. In SSIS I can run this Package and this value is converted to: 175.0684557107

Comment: If it's a decimal point, then that's why you're getting a failure. Either ignore truncation errors, or be very specific (you'll need to put the value in a `numeric` that can hold that scale, round it to 10 decimal places, and then convert it again).

Comment: Could you please explain me why I can run the package in SSIS without error and not on SQL Server?

Comment: Different language settings maybe?